# Vector iterator not dereferenceable when changing iterator comparisson

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

The following code snippet gives the error message at run time of:

Debug assertion failed: Vector iterator not dereferenceable

```
 for(it=stat1vec.begin(); *(it)>=investigated_stat; it++, positioner++)
    {


        if(*it==investigated_stat)
            equalwith++;

    }
```

When changed to:

```
for(it=stat1vec.begin(); *(it)==investigated_stat; it++, positioner++)
        {


            if(*it==investigated_stat)
                equalwith++;

        }
```

The code works perfectly.

All the has been done is to change >= to ==

Why is this?

Thanks very much

Comment: `=` is an assignment, I think you meant to use `==`, right? Additionally, it's better to use `++it` than `it++` on iterators to avoid construction of a temporary object.

Comment: @hochl the optimizer will most probably exclude the temporary regardless of the operator.

Comment: It's good to get in the habit though.

Comment: True, but it's good to not rely on the optimizer too much.

Comment: @hochl yeah i copied and pasted from my compiler incorrectly somehow -it's == at my end.

Comment: Could you describe, in English, which elements of the vector you wish to iterate over, and which you wish to exclude? Actually, what are you really trying to do? Is this the whole loop body? What is `positioner`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test for the iterator to be a valid iterator before dereferencing it. Your loop will continue until `*it < investigated_stat` but it won't stop when none of the elements are `>= investigated_stat` and you iterate past the end of the vector.

The test in the for loop should be

```
it != stat1vec.end() && *it >= investigated_stat
```

Which makes the slightly modified `for`:

```
for(it = stat1vec.begin(); it != stat1vec.end() && *it >= investigated_stat; ++it, ++positioner)
    if(*it == investigated_stat)
        ++equalwith;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems at some point before reaching the end of the vector you assigned zero to `*(it)`: at this point the loop terminated. The logical comparison tried to find something different - and failed. I assume you meant to write `==` in the second loop as well.

Note that the idiomatic way to iterate over a sequence (when not using algorithms, that is) looks something like this:

```
for (it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end /* possible additional conditions */; ++it)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Kuhl yeah i copied and pasted from my compiler incorrectly somehow -it's == at my end.